# php pdo charset utf8 mysql : unable to find an accentuated field

Tags: javascript, php, database, character-encoding

I have got a table 'famille'

```
    CREATE TABLE famille (
      idf INTEGER(6) NOT NULL ,  
>>>>>>      nomf VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
      CONSTRAINT pk_famille 
        PRIMARY KEY (idf),
>>>>>>      CONSTRAINT un_famille_nomf 
>>>>>>      UNIQUE (nomf)
    )ENGINE = InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8; <<<<<<<<<
```

When adding a new 'famille', i have to check constraints : the unique constraint refer to a text field.

Examples :

```
idf nomf
100 Actinidiacées   
110 Aizoaceae   
120 Amaranthacées   
130 Amaryllidacées (Liliacées)  
140 Apiacées (Ombellifères)
...
```

I use asynchronous query Javascript/Php to check values in a form that enable to add a new 'famille' and that the value of the field 'fnom' in the form already exists in the table : when le input field is not accentuated, it works, but when there are accentuated characters, it does not work : the form is submit and I get a normal SQL error.

Form simplified :

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
<title>Gestion - Administration du site</title>
...
<link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css' type='Text/css'>
<script src="js/checkfamille.js?dev=1574345195"></script>
</head>
<body><h2 class='entete'>Les familles</h2>
...
<form name='frmNewfamille' id='frmNewfamille'  method='post' ><fieldset id='fs1'><legend><b>Informations</b></legend><div class='ligne'><span class='label'><label for='fidf'>Identifiant</label></span><span class='champs'>
<input type='number' size='6' minlength='6' maxlength='6' name='fidf' id='fidf' required value='' /></span>
</div><div class='ligne'><span class='label'><label for='fnomf'>Intitulé</label></span><span class='champs'>
<input type='text' size='40' minlength='40' maxlength='40' name='fnomf' id='fnomf' required value='' /></span></div></fieldset><fieldset>
<input type="hidden" id="valide" name="valide" hidden />

<input class='bouton' type='button' name='btnNewAfamille'  id='btnNewAfamille' value='Ajouter'
onclick='return checkfamille();' />
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>^^^^^^^^^^^

</fieldset>

</form>
...
```

Javascript :

```
function checkfamille()                                    
{ 
    var idf = document.forms["frmNewfamille"]["fidf"];               
    var nomf = document.forms["frmNewfamille"]["fnomf"]; 

    // somme checks
...
    // ajax call
...
return checkFamilleAjax('code.php?idf='+escape(idf.value)
+'&nomf='+escape(nomf.value)  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
+'&mode=insert'); 
...
function checkFamilleAjax(fichier, nom)
{
    var xhr_object;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) // FIREFOX
        xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) // IE
        xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else
        return(false);

  xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr_object.readyState == 4 && (xhr_object.status == 200 || xhr_object.status == 0)) {
     var reponse = (xhr_object.responseText).replace(/\s/g, "");
      if(reponse=="0") {
        document.getElementById("valide").value = "true";
        document.forms["frmNewfamille"].submit();
        return true;
      } else if(reponse=="1") {
        // set error fields on the form
     ....
    } 
  }

  xhr_object.open("GET", fichier, true);
  xhr_object.send(null);
}
```

PHP code :

```
<?php session_start();
// includes
...

$database = new Database();
$famille = new Famille($database);
try {
if ($mode == 'insert') {
    if (isset($_GET["idf"]) && isset($_GET["nomf"])) {
        // checks if number already exists
        $database->query('SELECT idf FROM famille WHERE idf = :id;');
        $database->bind(':id', $_GET["idf"]);
        if ($result = $database->execute()) {  
           if ($database->rowCount() >0) {
            echo "1"; exit;
           }
        } else {
            echo "7 ". $database->getError(); exit;
        }
        // checks if name already exists
        $database->query('SELECT idf FROM famille WHERE nomf = :lname;');
        $database->bind(':lname', $_GET["nomf"]);
        if ($result = $database->execute()) {  
           if ($database->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo "2"; exit;
           } 
        } else {
            echo "8 ". $database->getError(); exit;
        }
        echo "0"; exit;
    } else {
        echo "9"; exit;
    }
...
```

Here is the  value of $_POST  from my form :

```
    Array ( [fidf] => 3214 [fnomf] => Rosacées [valide] => true )
```

and here is the query error :

```
    Erreur SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate 
    entry 'Rosacées' for key 'un_famille_nomf'
```

I have checked 
- all sources files : utf8 OK
- the database data
- php/mysql connexion parameters and code :

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");  
define("DB_USER", "xxxx");  
define("DB_PASS", "xxxx");  
define("DB_NAME", "xxxx");
define("DB_CHARSET", "utf8");
```

and a database class :

```
class Database
{
private $host = DB_HOST;  
private $user = DB_USER;  
private $pass = DB_PASS;  
private $dbname = DB_NAME;
private $charset = DB_CHARSET;

private $dbh;  
private $error;

private $stmt;  

public function __construct(){   
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname. ';charset=' .  $this->charset;
    // Options  
    $options = array(  
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,  
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"  
    );  

    try{  
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options); 
    $this->dbh->exec("SET NAMES utf8;");    
    }   
    catch(PDOException $e){  
    $this->error = $e->getMessage();  
    }  
}
...
```

May be I miss something ?

Thanks for help.

### ****EDIT****

Just after writing this message, I wonder if it does not come from escape(nomf.value) in the call of PHP asynchronous php code... I remove 'escape' and that works !!!

```
return checkFamilleAjax('code.php?idf='+idf.value
+'&nomf='+nomf.value
+'&mode=insert');
```

Javascript 'escape' change characters (accuentuated for example) to hexadecimal value : (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape * change * from french to english reference)

```
escape("abc123");     // "abc123"
escape("äöü");        // "%E4%F6%FC"
escape("ć");          // "%u0107"
```

This function is obsolete and 'encodeURI' ou 'encodeURIComponent' should be use when necessary.

Comment: Check to see if all files (JS/HTML also) are encoded/saved as UTF-8. Maybe just one isn't and is causing the encoding problem. Check also if the UTF-8 has the (BOM) byte order mark embedded or not.

Comment: Yes i have checked all files. The problem comes from the use of the 'encode'  Javascript function that convert accentuated characters to hexadecimal. I removed it and all is ok. You can see in an edit part of the post. Thank you.

Comment: How can I mark the post as solved ? Thank you if an admin can do it and delete this comment.

Comment: *Hm.....*, how to mark it as solved. I know you said that you removed the offending function call but that in a way doesn't completely solve the issue. I'll let you decide what to do. I'm glad you were able to continue though.